# Saddle Frame: What's the most idiomatic way to count NaN values?

Tags: scala, saddle

I build a Scala Frame like so e.g.

```
import org.saddle._
import scala.util.Random

val rowIx = Index(0 until 200)
val colIx = Index(0 until 100)

// create example having 15% of NaNs
val nanPerc = 0.15
val nanLength = math.round(nanPerc*rowIx.length*colIx.length).toInt
val nanInd = Random.shuffle(0 until rowIx.length*colIx.length).take(nanLength)
val rawMat = mat.rand(rowIx.length, colIx.length)
// contents gives a single array in row major
val rawMatContents = rawMat.contents
nanInd foreach { i => rawMatContents.update(i, Double.NaN) }

val df = Frame(rawMat, rowIx, colIx)

// now I'd like to test that the number of NaNs is correct but 
// most functions for this purpose in Frame e.g. countif exclude NaNs
df.???
```

What's the most idiomatic (Scala, Saddle) way to count the number of NaNs?

Comment: `countif` is implemented as `.filterFoldLeft(t => sd.notMissing(t) && test(t))(0)((a,b) => a + 1)`, so how about `.filterFoldLeft(sd.isMissing)(0)((a,b) => a + 1)`? [ref](https://github.com/saddle/saddle/blob/5acef9f852623f940cce071c7d17e59be00a0f81/saddle-core/src/main/scala/org/saddle/stats/VecStats.scala#L441)

Comment: Hi, thank you! you are shownig a vector and I operate on Frames, could you make a complete answer please rather than comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frame.countif` [is implemented as](https://github.com/saddle/saddle/blob/99bdb486361b9204df6a2dc45de86ce92803ede5/saddle-core/src/main/scala/org/saddle/stats/FrameStats.scala#L64):

```
def countif(test: T => Boolean)(implicit ev: S2Stats): Series[CX, Int] = frame.reduce(_.countif(test))
```

while `Vec.countif` [is implemented as](https://github.com/saddle/saddle/blob/99bdb486361b9204df6a2dc45de86ce92803ede5/saddle-core/src/main/scala/org/saddle/stats/VecStats.scala#L441):

```
def countif(test: Double => Boolean): Int = r.filterFoldLeft(t => sd.notMissing(t) && test(t))(0)((a,b) => a + 1)
```

We can use the same but remove `test` and invert the NaN check:

```
vec.filterFoldLeft(x => x.isNaN)(0)((a, b) => a + 1)
```

To run this on a `Frame`:

```
frame.reduce(_.filterFoldLeft(x => x.isNaN)(0)((a, b) => a + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple and direct way:

```
retDf.toMat.contents.filter(x => x.isNaN).length
```